# How can I multiprocess a single function thousands of time?

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing

I'm using OpenCV to compare thousands of images to one reference image. The process is very lengthy and I'm considering multiprocessing as a way to accelerate it.

How should I make it so that it'll do the "cv.matchTemplate(...)" function for each image, and without looping re-doing the function on the same image?

```
def myFunction():
    
    values_for_each_image =[]
    
    for image in thousands_of_images:
        result = cv.matchTemplate(reference_image, image, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        
        values_for_each_image.append(result[1])
     
     return values_for_each_image
```

Theoretically, I know that I could do something like this (but it's unrealistic for thousands of images):

```
def do_image1():
    return cv.matchTemplate(reference_image, image1, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

def do_image2():
    return cv.matchTemplate(reference_image, image2, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_image1)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_image2)

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
...
```

Comment: It is naïve to think that creating as many processes as possible will quicken your program. Your machine cannot perform more tasks in parallel than it has CPUs (physical or virtual), and memory/disk accesses can be a serious bottleneck. In addition, multithreading is lighter than multiprocessing and should be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would solve it using concurrent.futures:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def do_image(reference_image, image):
    return(cv.matchTemplate(reference_image, image, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED))

def myFunction():
    values_for_each_image = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(20) as executor:
        results = {executor.submit(do_image, reference_image, image) for image in thousands_of_images}
        for result in as_completed(results):
            values_for_each_image.append(result.result())
    return(values_for_each_image)
```

Comment: This cut execution time by 75%! Thanks!
Now I just need to tweak the output a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Pool](https://kenmeitechnologies-my.sharepoint.com/personal/alejandro_mor_kenmei_ai/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx) from python's multiprocessing library, instead of individual processes. The pool will take care of launching each process as necessary.

Seeing as your function does not have any parameters, I would say that you could get the best results by using the pool's [apply](https://kenmeitechnologies-my.sharepoint.com/personal/alejandro_mor_kenmei_ai/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx) or the [apply_async](https://kenmeitechnologies-my.sharepoint.com/personal/alejandro_mor_kenmei_ai/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx) functions.